# Can't initialize VM's on HyperV Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, powershell, virtual-machines, hyper-v

I'm really stuck with this and I can't understand why I sunddendly can't make ANY VM to start succesfully in my system.

I had just one VM, and it was working perfectly, then for some reasons I booted into another system, then came back into WinServer 2012 and couldn't make them start anymore.

This is the traceback:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Start-VM Ubuntu
Start-VM : 'Ubuntu' could not initialize. (Virtual machine ID 1ECB1603-A320-4BAF-8452-9962768F5D49)
You do not have permission to perform the operation. Contact your administrator if you believe you should have
permission to perform this operation.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-VM Ubuntu
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied:  (Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMTask:VMTask) [Start-VM], Virtualization
OperationFailedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :  AccessDenied,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.StartVMCommand
```

Seems clearly to be a permission issue of course, but I just don't get it, how?

And, if I start it from HyperV's graphic interface, then it shows:

```
An error occurred while attempting to start the selected virtual machine(s) 'Ubuntu' could not initialize (Virtual machine ID 'ID')
```

I deleted my previous VM, not before I had it exported, THEN created a new VM, with new ID, using the same disk, same error above.

I even created a new one, without any disk, same error.

Does anyone know what could have happened?

Is there some script or configuration I should look for?

I've searched and searched even on msdn but nothing, I dont get it...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Many Thanks in Advance!

**EDIT**

Following User @Peter Hahndorf suggestion, I ran `icacls.exe` and this is the output:

```
PS C:\Users\Public\Documents> icacls .\Hyper-V
.\Hyper-V BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
      BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
      BUILTIN\Hyper-V Administrators:(F)
      BUILTIN\Hyper-V Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
      BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
      CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
      NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\Virtual Machines:(R,WD,AD)
      NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\Virtual Machines:(CI)(IO)(GR,WD,AD)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

It surely is about permissions, but how? I didn't "touch" anything, the folder is now placed under `C:\Users\Public\Documents` instead of `C:\Users\Administrator\My Documents`

How can I grant Administrator permission again?

Comment: How did you create the VHD for the VM?

Comment: With the HyperV's VM manager

Comment: Just chose Create VHD for this VM put on size and memory and that's it, but the problem is, it was workng perfectly before, and now, even if I create a new VM even without VHD it just won't start, same error

Comment: If the cmdlet is failing to start a vm it is likely the result of insufficient permissions from the account performing the commands. Is your Powershell session running as admin?

Comment: Hi, yes, it is running as admin...

Comment: What are the NTFS permissions on the directory where you trying to create the files, (the default folders under Hyper-V Setting), use icacls.exe and add the results to your question.

Comment: Read [Start a Command Prompt as an Administrator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj717276(v=ws.11).aspx); appliable to `powershell` instead of `cmd` as well.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf Hello! Damn, yeah, it is surely about permissions, I've edited my question with the icacls.exe output, any ideas on how to grant permissions there? I'm not really fond on Windows Server 2012, Thank You!

Comment: @NeoVe - The NTFS permissions look fine, they are the default. But it seems you don't have a problem with creating a new VM, but actually starting an existing one. It also seems you are running as elevated administrator, but double-check: `whoami /group` to confirm that `Administrators` and/or `Hyper-V Administrators` is an `enabled group`.  Anything in the logs, use Event Viewer to review `Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS-Admin` and other Hyper-V logs. Something seems wrong, you could try re-installing the Hyper-V role.

Comment: Hi, Yes, well, but if I create a new one the same problem appears, and already tried reinstalling the role, anyways, I'm going to double check, Thanks